# Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object?

Tags: java, android, serialization

I get "Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object" error on this code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                tvResult.setText("Povezivanje s bazom u tijeku...");
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY");

                Details details = new Details();
                details.host=etHost.getText().toString();
                details.user=etUsername.getText().toString();
                details.pass=etPass.getText().toString();
                details.database=etBaza.getText().toString();

                new GetData(tvResult).execute("");

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("Detalji", details);
                i.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(i);

            }
```

Here is also my Details class:

```
public class Details implements Serializable 
    {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String host;
        private String pass;
        private String user;
        private String database;
    }
```

Everything is working good till `startActivity(i)` command, anyone have idea why?

Comment: If that is all that you have in your Details class then it shouldn't even do anything? I'm pretty sure it shouldn't even compile. Those are private variables, you can't access them in public ways like that.

Comment: it's compiled and there are no errors with private vars, tho they are stored into the intent

Comment: I am confused as to how that works, `details.host=etHost.getText().toString();` (and the other details.* calls) should give the error that you either need to change the visibility to default or you need to add a getter and setter for your variable.

Comment: i changed privacy but still same error

Comment: @zgc7009 This actually works when Details is an Inner class. I was wondering too and just tested it.

Comment: @Ascorbin Thanks very much, didn't have the capabilities to test right now. Learn new things every day :P. Thought that they would still need to be set to a protected visibility at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Details class have you overridden writeToParcel and readFromParcel?

```
@Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
}
```

Details needs to implement Parceleable if you want to pass complex objects via intents.

Details class needs to be in it's own file you are not implementing parcelable.

Comment: above is everything that i have in that Details class

Comment: just making sure that none of those variables are null when you pass it to the intent and can you post your logcat just to verify?

Comment: sry I'm pretty new to Eclipse and don't know how to export whole logcat log

Comment: oh you can just send part of it. the one with the error. its' easier to copy from the command line using "adb logcat"  you on a mac or pc?

Comment: Move it to it's own file and it should work. please click accept if this answers your question.

Comment: omg what a dumb move to do, thx alot was trying to fix that for few hours

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement `Parcelable` to your data class `Details`.

```
public class Details implements Serializable, Parcelable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String host;
    private String pass;
    private String user;
    private String database;

    public Details(Parcel in){
       this.host = in.readString();
       this.pass = in.readString();
       this.user = in.readString();
       this.database = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.host);
        dest.writeString(this.pass);
        dest.writeString(this.user);
        dest.writeString(this.database);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Details> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Details>() {
        public Details createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Details(in); 
        }

        public Details[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Details[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Now I tried to write something what should work for you, but I am not 100% sure it will, so do some aditional reading from here:

- http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html
- http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/06/parcelable-how-to-do-that-in-android.html

Comment: Don't need to implement Serializable do you? Seems Parcelable should handle everything.

Comment: Yeah, it's left from the author's code I copied. It might still be of use as you might use it as Serializable too, but it is said that serialization is not fast in Android.